# Getting HTTP serverName and serverPort from HttpSession

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0

Does anyone know of a way to get to the server name and port usually contained in the `HttpRequest` from a `HttpSession` object ?

In other words I need the results of `HttpServletRequest#getServerName()` and `HttpServletRequest#getServerPort()` methods, while only having a `HttpSession` object.

I understand what I'm asking for is a "hack", but I currently need a hacky way to do it.

Comment: Would be usefull to implement a Filter to provide you this?

Comment: I can see the server name in jsessionid cookie's domain property, but not the port.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is kind of a hack, but as suggested by Jorge Campos, you could use a Filter to put a pointer to the request into the session at the beginning and remove it at the end. Something like :

```
public class ReqFilter implements Filter {
    ...
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();
        session.setAttribute("request", request);
        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        catch(ServletException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            session.setAttribute("request", null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: putting only strings you need in attributes would be better.